# Compile-time Size of Struct Minus Padding

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-mpl, compile-time-constant, boost-fusion

I'm trying to use Boost MPL and Fusion to calculate the size of a struct exclusive of any padding. This is my current best attempt:

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QKealoruACDrwdUT)

```
template<class T>
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_members(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
    namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

    //This works, but only for structs containing exactly 4 members...
    typedef typename mpl::apply<mpl::unpack_args<mpl::vector<mpl::_1, mpl::_2, mpl::_3, mpl::_4>::type >, T>::type member_types;

    typedef typename mpl::transform<member_types, mpl::sizeof_<mpl::_1> >::type member_sizes;
    typedef typename mpl::accumulate<member_sizes, mpl::int_<0>, mpl::plus<mpl::_1, mpl::_2> >::type sum;
    return sum();
}

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT(
    (), Foo_t,
    (std::uint8_t,  a)
    (std::uint16_t, b)
    (std::uint32_t, c)
    (std::uint64_t, d)
);
static_assert(sizeof_members<struct Foo_t>() == 15);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof_members = " << sizeof_members<struct Foo_t>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof = " << sizeof(struct Foo_t) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
sizeof_members<struct Foo_t>() = 15
sizeof(struct Foo_t) = 16
```

I can transform a Sequence of types to a Sequence of integers containing the size of each type, and I can compute the sum over that Sequence, but I'm having trouble with the first step of turning the struct into a Sequence of types. The Fusion docs say that [BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html) generates boilerplate to define and adapt an arbitrary struct as a model of Random Access Sequence, which I believe should be compatible with mpl::transform, however there seems to be some glue code that I'm missing to make this work. My current approach using mpl::unpack_args works but only for structs with exactly four fields.

How can I extend this to arbitrary structs with more or fewer fields?

Comment: `How can I extend this to arbitrary structs?` What are "arbitrary structs"? You mean, to structs not declared using `BOOST_FUSION`? You can't - C++ doesn't have reflection.

Comment: Actually, you can do it at least for AggregateTypes in C++14 and C++17. The idea is, you can count the max. number of arguments you can pass to the default aggregate initialization (SFINAE). Then you can delegate to a structural decomposition and you have the types.

Comment: @KamilCuk any struct adapted with Boost Fusion but with more or fewer fields. My current implementation only works for the specific example given with four fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged this C++17, the answer is: don't use Boost.MPL. Given C++11 even, the metaprogramming library you want is [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) - it's substantially better in all respects.

The newer, easier-to-use, ridiculously-more-compile-time-efficient version of Boost.Fusion that you want to use is [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html):

```
struct Foo_t {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Foo_t,
        (std::uint8_t, a),
        (std::uint16_t, b),
        (std::uint32_t, c),
        (std::uint64_t, d)
    );
};
```

And the reason you want to use Boost.Hana is because `sizeof_members` (for any number of members) can be written as:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr auto sizeof_members() -> size_t
{
    return hana::fold(hana::accessors<T>(), size_t{},
        [](size_t s, auto mem){
            return s + sizeof(hana::second(mem)(std::declval<T>()));
        });
}

static_assert(sizeof_members<Foo_t>() == 15);
```

This mostly reads exactly like what you actually want to do: you want to fold over all the members, starting at 0, with an accumulation function that adds the size of the next member (`accessors<T>()` gives you a Sequence of pairs where the `first` is the name of the accessor and the `second` is a function that takes an object and returns that member).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/gtgwHF).

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted and much more direct than the path I was heading down.

Comment: What is to do when my struct member is a struct too, how do I call sizeof_members recursivley?