# Compile size of a struct minus padding recusively

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-hana

I have a similar Problem as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148977/compile-time-size-of-struct-minus-padding).
I want to get the size of struct at compile time, including all the substructs without the compiler specific padding added.

```
struct Bar {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Bar,
      (std::uint8_t, a),
      (std::uint16_t, b)
   );
};

struct Foo {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Foo,
      (std::uint8_t, a),
      (std::uint16_t, b),
      (std::uint32_t, c),
      (std::uint64_t, d),
      (Bar, bar)
    );
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto bytesize() -> size_t
{
 if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value)
    return sizeof(T);
  else if constexpr (std::is_class<T>::value)
  {
    return hana::fold_left(
      hana::accessors<T>(), 0, [](auto total, auto member) {
        // I want to call bytesize recusively here:
        return bytesize<decltype(hana::second(member)(std::declval<T>()))>() + total;
      });
  }  
}

static_assert(bytesize<Foo>() == 18);
```

As I don't want to include the padding, I expect the size of the struct `Foo` to be 18 (including the size of the substruct `Bar`) but the code in the linked question does include the padding in the calculation and gives me a size of 19. The problem lies therein that the function should call bytesize recursively on all structs it encounters.

A minimal example which does not work as intended can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jW4e6d).

Comment: your minimal example is not about getting the size of the struct. It is about asserting a specific size.

Comment: @idclev463035818 check the commented out part in the function `bytesize`, this is the part which does not work

Comment: there is no function bytesize, please include the code in the question

Comment: What is the outcome you expect? What is the output you get? Please take some time to [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, you *are* aware of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I'm aware of this issue, that's why I'm using boost::hana.

Comment: @idclev463035818 The linked question which I "instructed" to read does mention the problem with padding, I assumed that mentionig it another time does not aid the cause but I can add it again in the question

Comment: @Scheff ups you're right, copy paste error

Comment: FYI: I got rid of the compile error by adding `else return 0;` but it still doesn't match the `static_assert()`: [Fixed _here_ on CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1o63fM)

Comment: Why do you assume that Boost Hana does something that makes the compiler omit the padding? Have you ran the code through the preprocessor to see what all the macro invocations really expand to, and what the structure really is?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude boost::hana doesn't do anything with the padding, it just gives me the possibility to cycle my struct members at compile time

Comment: Okay I think I get you now: You use Boost Hana to add some meta-data and reflection abilities available. Like for example enumerate the individual members of the structure, and getting their respective size.

Comment: exactly the BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT macro gives me this ability

Comment: Now please answer us this: Why do you need this? What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Always please ask about the actual problem directly, possibly presenting what you have tried (like in this question) as your attempt, including a description of the problems you have with your attempt. It's okay if it's just plain curiosity, but then please state so in the question itself. We might be able to help you with the original problem instead, and maybe have *other* solutions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem is described in the first sentence of the question, I am asking this question to experts in boost::hana, that's why I'm inclundig this tag, I assumed therefore I don't have to explain the workings of boost::hana to ask my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue with returned types which are not what you expect (extra `&&`). `std::decay_t` fixes the issue:

```
return hana::fold_left(
    hana::accessors<T>(), 0, [](auto total, auto member) {
        using member_type = std::decay_t<decltype(hana::second(member)(std::declval<T>()))>;
        constexpr auto member_size = bytesize<member_type>();

        return total + member_size;
    });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1E8KoY)

Answer (score 0):

Size of the structure is more, because there is **padding** or **alignment**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

On `gcc` and `clang` you can use `__attribute__((__packed__))`

```
struct Bar {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Bar,
      (std::uint8_t, a),
      (std::uint16_t, b)
  );
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Example
https://godbolt.org/z/odMTEs

Note, on x86, packed structs does NOT have negative effect. Not measurable at least.

On Arm they also work "fast enought".

However on some other architectures they might be really slow or even they can "crash" the CPU.

Comment: I absolutly aware of padding, that's why I'm using boost::hana to cycle the members of the struct and get the sizes of the members separately. I don't want to rely on some compiler specific attributes for the task

Comment: Well. if you pack it, it works. Could it be something Hana-related?

Comment: wait, it compiles now. you fixed it?

Comment: 2*1Byte + 2*2Byte + 4Byte + 8Byte = 18Byte

Comment: I knew it, but I thought the macro adds invisible members